# how I can copy the text in a specified field, without mention the line number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have the next code :

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
            var link = File.ReadLines(path + "test.txt").ToArray();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + "test2.txt");
            foreach (var txt in link  )
            {
                if (txt.Contains("Output="))
                {
                    var outputPath = txt.Split('=')[1];

                    if (File.Exists(path + "test2.txt"))
                    {
                        var modifiedLines = lines.Select(line =>
             {
                 if (line.StartsWith("outlog=\""))
                 {
                     return string.Format("outlog=\"{0}\"", outputPath);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     return line;
                 }
             });

             File.WriteAllLines(path+ "test2.txt", modifiedLines);
                    }


            }

            }
```

With this code I whan to copy what is after equel  from `Output="C:\temp\out.log"`(who is in test.txt), after equal in  `outlog=`(who is in test2.txt).
How I can copy the text who exists in one text file `test.txt`, in a specified location from a second field `test2.txt`, **without** mentioned the line number ?

Here I put just a row, but in my files text I have many rows, but I think I make this to work, I handle with another rows.

`test.txt` have

```
Licfile="C:\temp\lic.lic"
Output="C:\temp\out.log"
Title="name"
```

`test2.txt` have

```
outlog=
license=
lmgr_files=
license_path=
```

and after runing the code the `test2.txt` I want to looks like this:

```
outlog="C:\temp\out.log"
license_path="C:\temp\lic.lic"
lmgr_files=false
license=true
```

Comment: I didn't notice any mention of the line number.

Comment: It would be nice to see a few lines of both files and a result that you want to achive.

Comment: in my code I tried to evict, but I put that condition, because I don't want to receive an answer with line number

Comment: I edited my post and now you can see the structure of both text files

Comment: What if you read test2.txt into an associative array?  So that each line in test2.txt becomes an element.  So you'd have something like Test2Array("outlog") and Test2Array("license_path") and so on.  Then when you read test.txt, split the line, test whether the that element exists, and if so, set the value with the remainder of the result of the split, like Test2Array("outlog") = outputPath

Comment: I will so thankful if you can give me the cod to do this, because I'm beginner, and I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: What is related _lmgr_ with?

Comment: The code above is in a button click and returns before a file is written. Why? Should the code handle existing nodes in file 2? One needs to write a clear objective, with all permutations, before asking for help; this question has too many unanswered questions to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about your problem but i just want to try to give you an opinion. I hope it may be help you. But line numbers are really important for these problem.

```
String[] arrayOld = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt");
String[] arrayNew = new string[arrayOld.Length];

 if (arrayOld[0].Contains("Licfile=")) // If statements could be more
  {
    Array.Copy(arrayOld,0,arrayNew,0,2); // How many line will add
  }

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\test2.txt", arrayNew[i] + Environment.NewLine); // It'll add all lines
   }
```

P.S.: Don't forget to add strings like **lineOne = "outlog=" + locString;** etc.

Comment: I don't need to add rows I have that rows, all I want is to write what is after equal in test.txt, after equal in test2.txt .